# Python 3.7.4 downloaded from official site but I get python 2.7.10 installed instead

Tags: python, installation, version

I downloaded the python installation file from:

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-374/

But when I install it and in console check python version I get 2.7.10 version instead of 3.7.4. I don't know why is that. I am new to python.

Do you have any ideas why I get version 2.7.10 instead of 3.7.4?

I use Macbook with OSX High Sierra version 10.13.6.

I already tried to reinstall python by downloading this file from this website:

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-374/

But when I installed it again I still get 2.7.10 version instead of 3.7.4.

I only used python -V in the console and get 2.7.10 version response.

I expected version 3.7.4 to be installed. Instead of this, I get 2.7.10. I don't know why is that.

Comment: Try with python3 -V :D

Comment: Did you already have Python 2 installed? Try running `python3` instead of `python`.

Comment: Yes, python3 -V work. Sorry for the silly question but I am new to python and couldn't find anywhere answer. Cheers :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have both versions installed. 
Type python3 -V

Comment: That's the correct answer. Thank you, @Jeremiah Gelb.